# Downloads of large files fail behind load balancer in GCP

Tags: file, google-cloud-platform, download, load-balancing

I am hosting an express.js application in the Google Cloud. The application runs in a docker container on a compute instance and is reachable via a https-load-balancer. The application offers an endpoint to download files for authorized users. The files are hosted in a gooogle cloud storage bucket. When a user wants to download a file the application creates a file stream to read the file from cloud storage and pipes the file content into the response (the application acts as a proxy so users do not have to access the cloud storage directly). This works perfectly fine for smaller files but when downloading larger files the connection always gets terminated around 800-1200 MBs.

Here is a typical result of a download via curl:

```
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 1977551872
< Content-Type: application/vmware
< Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.ova"
< Via: 1.1 google
< Alt-Svc: clear
< 
{ [737 bytes data]
 53 1885M   53 1013M    0     0  75.1M      0  0:00:25  0:00:13  0:00:12 71.4M* transfer closed with 863362048 bytes remaining to read
* stopped the pause stream!
 56 1885M   56 1062M    0     0  75.3M      0  0:00:25  0:00:14  0:00:11 72.0M
* Closing connection 0
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [2 bytes data]
curl: (18) transfer closed with 863362048 bytes remaining to read
```

When I connect to the compute instance via ssh and trigger the download with curl on localhost (directly accessing the application and bypassing the load balancer, etc.) then everything works perfectly fine so I assume that it is not an application problem. Externally I tried to download large files with several curl options to localize the problem:

- Ignoring the Content-Length doesn't help
- Enforcing HTTP 1.1 instead of HTTP/2 doesn't help
- Limiting the bandwith shows that it is not a timeout problem but a file size problem. When limiting the bandwidth the connection stays open several minutes as expected.

I also could not find anything in the GCP documentation mentioning any limits in the load-balancer which could lead to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting the default Google Load Balancer HTTP response timeout, which is 30 seconds.
This can be increased in the configuration page of the backend that is connected to your load balancer to suit your needs. Effectively, increasing this will allow for serving larger files.

Have a look at the documentation for a more detailed explanation:
Load balancer settings explanation: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#timeouts_and_retries

Backend service setting explanation: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#backend_service_settings

How to configure: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#timeout-setting

Answer (score 0):

The maximum HTTP transfer (request/response) is 32 MB.

This is documented for App Engine [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas) and Cloud Run [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_limits) which use the same frontend service discussed [here](https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/security_whitepapers_march2018.pdf).

The solution is to use Google Cloud Storage for objects larger than 32 MB.

Comment: I am not using App Engine. My application is hosted on a compute instance behind a https load balancer and I already use Cloud Storage to host my files. My application just serves as a proxy to download the files from cloud storage. I could not find any documentation on limits there. I am also able to download more than 32 MBs. Cutoffs usually start around 800MBs. Stackdriver also doesn't show any logs related to usage errors.

Comment: @Mortymus - Did you read my links? These services I mentioned including HTTP(S) load balancers use the same Google Frontend (which is a service name - GFE) which controls the size of Request/Response.

Comment: Yes I read them. My current understanding from the documentation is that HTTPS(S) load balancers are implemented by the GFEs like you mentioned. But it does not mention that there is a general size limit in all GFE implemented services. From my current understanding the 32 MB limit cannot be true for the load balancer service, mainly for two reasons:
1. I am able to download files via the load balancer which are larger than 32 MBs (several 100 MBs for example).
2. The load balancer can also use the cloud storage as a backend service which would not make any sense if there was a size limit.

Comment: I recommend that you open a support case. When you get a response post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue now. I think that Google Classic Load Balancer (in Europe?) is overloaded because thousands of TCP ZeroWindow packets appear in a dump.

The newer Load Balancer (Global) is faster, but sometimes slow but not so much.

See [details](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/Slow-download-from-Europe-via-classic-HTTP-load-balancer/m-p/441473#M1021).